# Angular 4 animation state changes

Tags: angular, web-animations, angular-animations

I have an animation applied to two divs to animate them in and out of the void state.

See: https://plnkr.co/edit/uCdBafYG7NZxVVppiTpo?p=preview

Html:

```
 <div *ngIf="shown" [@flipEnterExitAnimation]="state">
      <div style="border: 1px solid black">Front</div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="!shown" [@flipEnterExitAnimation]="state">
      <div style="border: 1px solid black">Back</div>
    </div>
```

Typescript:

```
     this.state = this.state === 'backwards' ? null : 'backwards';
      this.shown = !this.shown;

      /*
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.shown = !this.shown;
      },
      1);*/
```

These animations work, however when the state changes it is not applied to the first animation. I can fix this by delaying the animation for 1ms, but this is ugly and feels a bit hacky.

Is there a neater way to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way is to use change detection (`ChangeDetectorRef`):

```
 import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

 // snip

private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef;

constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
   this.changeDetectorRef = changeDetectorRef;
}

beginAnim() {
  this.state = this.state === 'backwards' ? null : 'backwards';
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  this.shown = !this.shown;
}
```